# $\operatorname{ker}A\subseteq\operatorname{im} A$ an open condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is a simple to state linear algebra question---let's work over $\mathbb{C}$ (but algebraic explanations are appreciated, as opposed to analytic arguments :) )

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and consider the algebra $\text{End}(V)$ equipped with the Zariski topology.  Then is the condition that for $A\in\text{End}(V)$ we have $\operatorname{ker}A\subseteq \operatorname{im}A$ open?  In other words, is the following set open in $\text{End}(V)$:
$$
\{A\in\text{End}(V):\operatorname{ker}A\subseteq\operatorname{im}A\}.
$$
If you don't like the Zariski topology then the analytic topology is okay too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set is not even open in the usual topology, unless $V$ has dimension $\le 1$.

For example, in dimension $2$, the set contains $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, but not $\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ for $\varepsilon\ne 0$.

Since the Zariski topology is coarser than the usual topology, your set is not open there either.